# Getting CDT as an Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, ide, c++, c

I've always used Eclipse for Java development. However recently, I've wanted to add other language functionality to my favorite IDE. I got it to work with python and no I need C/C++.

A search on the marketplace yeilded nothing for CDT and I can't seem to find it. Is it a plugin? I'm confused as to how to make it work with my current IDE.

Comment: I stopped using it when I moved to NetBeans for PHP development. I do remember that some time around Ubunto 10.10 it was no longer in the repository :-(   However, you can download it from http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/   but that looks like a complete install of Eclipse, not just a plugin. Looks like you are going to have to do a bit of digging around.  Maybe try asking on their forum?

Comment: Good to know I'm not the only one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in Eclipse, click `Help -> Install New Software...` Select your update site in the "Work with" box. This is most likely Helios. If it does not exist, type this in it http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios (or another version) and click Add. Once the list is fully loaded, open "Programming Languages" and install the "C/C++ Development Tools".
[image: Installing new software in Eclipse]